# require()ing a dll within a subdirectory in Lua

Tags: lua, multilingual, lua-api, cross-language

Lua's `require(<name>)` function, if called on a `<name>.dll`, will look for a function called `luaopen_<name>`.

What should I do if I want to say `require("folder1.folder2.library")`? It's not like I can name a function `luaopen_folder1.folder2.library`.

I am looking for a way to do this that doesn't involve changing Lua's module path—i.e. a way to do this that scales with the complexity of a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the function `luaopen_folder1_folder2_library`.